# Overloading '==' operator in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to overload the '==' operator for String class in Swift:

```
public func ==(left: String, right: String) -> Bool
{
    let ret = left.caseInsensitiveCompare(right) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame ? true : false;

    return ret;
}
```

But whenever I try to use this on code:

```
func test(a: String) -> Bool
{
    if  (a == "Just Testing") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The following compiler error message is being displayed:

**Ambiguous use of operator '=='**

How can I fix this ?
Thx.

Comment: Trying to change the semantics of built-in types (here: string comparison) is a very, very bad idea. You're likely to make unexpected things fail in unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Cristik mentions, since there's already an `==` operator defined for two strings, you can't usefully define another one.  One option would be to define a new operator:

```
infix operator ==^ {}

func ==^(lhs:String, rhs:String) -> Bool {
    return lhs.caseInsensitiveCompare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
}

"abc" ==^ "ABC"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because Swift already defines the `==` operator for two String values:

```
public func ==(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool
```

and it doesn't know which one to pick, as you also provide an implementation.